# Increment 2 different Ids based on selected option

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, counter, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to update a working solution of incrementing one ID based on several conditions, so I was using the `ROW()` function without any issue. But now I'm trying to increment 2 different IDs based on selected option as shown in the screenshot below, where I've started the following so far:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A),COUNTIFS(A2:A, A2:A, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A),A2:A,"Option 2"),))`

Can anyone bring some light on this scenario: thanks

**Link of spreadsheet illustrating my situation**: [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pexyWDEBefiJom5gliG5iT9mLbUC_x0E74o48C7s3Qc)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You have to first check if the value is `Option 1`/`Option 2` or not. A way to do this without using [OR](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093306) (which can't be iterated over an array) is this:

```
IF(A2:A="Option 1",0,1)*IF(A2:A="Option 2",0,1)
```

- Next, you can wrap this into another `IF` so that the returned value depends on whether the previous condition is true. So, if option is not `1` nor `2`, the corresponding value should result from the count of all the previous values which are not `1` or `2`. So the [COUNTIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550) should check if the option is not `1` nor `2`. Something like this:

```
29999 + COUNTIFS(A2:A,"<>Option 1",A2:A,"<>Option 2",ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))
```

- Finally, if the option is `1` or `2`, the returned value should result from hte count of all previous `1` and `2` values. Since that's an `OR` condition, you have to sum two different `COUNTIFS`, one for option `1` and one for `2`. Could be like this:

```
9999 + COUNTIFS(A2:A,"=Option 1",ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A)) + COUNTIFS(A2:A,"=Option 2",ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))
```

- Putting it all together, it could be like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A2:A),IF(IF(A2:A="Option 1",0,1)*IF(A2:A="Option 2",0,1),
29999 + COUNTIFS(A2:A,"<>Option 1",A2:A,"<>Option 2",ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A)),
9999 + COUNTIFS(A2:A,"=Option 1",ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A)) + COUNTIFS(A2:A,"=Option 2",ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A))),""))
```

[image]

Comment: @lamblichus I've posted this comment earlier but I came back didn't find it: **Many thanks for your response and the step by step explanation to achieve the goal**.

Answer (score 2):

slight alternative:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,IF(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, H2&"$|"&H3&"$"),
 9999+COUNTIFS(REGEXMATCH(A2:A, H2&"$|"&H3&"$"),
               REGEXMATCH(A2:A, H2&"$|"&H3&"$"), ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A)), 
 29999+COUNTIFS(A2:A, "<>"&H2, A2:A, "<>"&H3, ROW(A2:A), "<="&ROW(A2:A)))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for suggesting another way of doing it, it helps to see how to solve a problem with different methods